# [[_TOC_]] doesn't work in VSTS/Azure DevOps anymore

Tags: azure-devops, markdown, tableofcontents

We use VSTS/Azure DevOps at work, and have recently updated all our README's and wiki's in our company to improve life for new starters and team switchers, and for general quality of life.

I've just noticed that the `[[_TOC_]]` **table of contents** element is suddenly very janky - only a few links work, whereas it linked beautifully a few weeks ago. IT still creates the table, but the table is pretty useless if only 10% of the items actually go to the expected view when you click on them.

Does anyone know what caused this, and if there's a fix? Should I raise a bug with Azure?

Thanks!

Comment: I've created a new wiki file in Azure DevOps see if the issue could be reproduced but with no luck. The `[[_TOC_]]` in my new created test wiki could work as expected. Can you share us your wiki especially the part where you met the issue so we can see what's happening?

Comment: Thanks Yang Shen, I've actually looked at the issue now (markdown never seems as important as actual programming), and have concluded that the problem lies with README's with emoji only.
Will have to use the boring old `[heading](#heading)` there.

Comment: Nice to know the issue has been resolved. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielleBooysen Please post what worked for you as an answer below, so it helps others running into similar issues. Thanks!